# Size of a simple class containing a single integer property in .NET

Tags: c#, debugging

I already watched a session from Mario Hewardt that mentions a class containing an integer property takes 16 bytes of space. I'd like to know how the size of a simple following class can result in 16?

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class MyClass
{
    public int Age;
}
```

The problem is that the integer takes 4 bytes of space (right?) so where the heck those 12 other bytes come from? I've also used Marshal.SizeOf to get the class size which resulted in 4:

```
int n = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MyClass));
//n == 4
```

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694423/size-of-a-class-object-in-net) and it seems that the above class holds 8 bytes of internal data (what are these data anyway?), 4 byte for the int value, and 4 bytes of unused space. So if it takes 16 byte, why Marshal.SizeOf returns 4? and if it takes 4, where those 8 bytes are gone? I'm truly confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Marshal.SizeOf(Type)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5s4920fa.aspx) returns the  size of the equivalent **unmanaged** type, i.e. how many bytes would the equivalent unmanaged type (e.g. a C++ class) take if it had the same field layout and packing. Note that this function is designed to work only with classes with the [[StructLayout]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.aspx) attribute with a LayoutKind of either `Explicit` or `Sequential`.

The memory used up when the CLR allocates an object on the managed heap depends on the internals of the CLR in question. [Drill Into .NET Framework Internals to See How the CLR Creates Runtime Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163791.aspx) is an article about the CLRv2 implementation of object allocation. Essentially, every object has two hidden fields - a sync block index and a type handle. The sync block is an internal structure used when an object is used with a `lock(obj) {}` statement. The type handle provides runtime type information about the given instance - it contains the object's method table, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, a class in C# is not just the fields id contains.
There has to be a virtual functions tables so you can use virtual & override keywords, and certainly few other things, like maybe a pointer to the type metadata...

The fact is you should not care... what's important is "how many bytes do I need to be able to rebuild the instance?". The answer is what Marshal.SizeOf gives you : 4.

Marshalling only the 4 bytes of the integer (yes you're right, it's 4 bytes), and knowing you want to deserialize a MyClass, then you have enough information to do it.