# Is it acceptable to return a canonical representation subclass from an abstract base class?

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, design-patterns

Edit 2: **TL;DR**: Is there a way not to break OO best practices while still satisfying the constraint that a bunch of things of the same kind have to be convertible to a canonical thing of that kind?

Also, please keep in mind that my question is about the general situation, not the specific example. This isn't a homework problem.

---

Suppose you have the following:

- an abstract base class that implements common functionality;
- a concrete derived class that serves as the canonical representation.

Now suppose you want any inheritor of the base class to be convertible to the canonical representation. One way of doing this is by having an abstract method in the base class that is meant to return a conversion of the inheritor as an instance of the canonical derived class.

However, it seems to be generally accepted that base classes should not know about any of their derived classes, and in the general case, I agree. However, in this scenario, this seems to be the best solution because it enables any number of derived classes, each with their own implementation we don't need to know anything about, to be interoperable via the conversion to the canonical representation that every derived class has to implement.

Would you do it differently? Why and how?

An example for geometric points:

```
// an abstract point has no coordinate system information, so the values
// of X and Y are meaningless
public abstract class AbstractPoint {
    public int X;
    public int Y;

    public abstract ScreenPoint ToScreenPoint();
}

// a point in the predefined screen coordinate system; the meaning of X 
// and Y is known
public class ScreenPoint : AbstractPoint {
    public ScreenPoint(int x, int y) {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

    public override ScreenPoint ToScreenPoint()
        => new ScreenPoint(X, Y);
}

// there can be any number of classes like this; we don't know anything
// about their coordinate systems and we don't care as long as we can
// convert them to `ScreenPoint`s
public class ArbitraryPoint : AbstractPoint {
    private int arbitraryTransformation;

    public ArbitraryPoint(int x, int y) {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

    public override ScreenPoint ToScreenPoint()
        => new ScreenPoint(X * arbitraryTransformation, Y * arbitraryTransformation);

    // (other code)
}
```

---

Edit 1: The reason `AbstractPoint` and `ScreenPoint` are not the same class is semantic. An `AbstractPoint` does not have a defined coordinate system, therefore the values of X and Y in an `AbstractPoint` instance are meaningless. A `ScreenPoint` does have a defined coordinate system, therefore the values of X and Y in a `ScreenPoint` instance have a well-defined meaning.

If `ScreenPoint` were the base class, then an `ArbitraryPoint` would be a `ScreenPoint`, which is not the case. An `ArbitraryPoint` can be converted to a `ScreenPoint`, but that does not mean that it `is-a` `ScreenPoint`.

If you are still unconvinced, consider that an arbitrary coordinate system `ACS1` can be defined as having a dynamic offset to the screen coordinate system `SCS`. This means the mapping between the two coordinate systems can vary with time, i.e. the point `ACS1 (1, 1)` can map to `SCS (10, 10)` at one moment, and `SCS (42, 877)` at another moment.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why a static class that handles this type of conversion wouldn't be an acceptable solution for your use case?

However, at this time I am failing to see what your proposed `ScreenPoint` class brings to the table, that could not be instead placed on `AbstractPoint`.  Can you expand upon this?

Comment: If everything is convertible to `ScreenPoint` it means, that `ScreenPoint` contains **only** data common to all classes. That suggests that `AbstractPoint` and `ScreenPoint` should be one class.

Comment: @ChrisThompson The reason the base class declares the conversion is to force every derived class to implement it. I'm not sure how that would work if there were a static class handling the conversion. I have tried to clarify the difference between `ScreenPoint` and `AbstractPoint` in my edit.

Comment: @MiroslavPolicki If `AbstractPoint` has only one method which is the `ToScreenPoint` method, You are better off creating an interface rather than an `abstract` class. Alternately, it makes more sense to create a generic `ScreenPoint` class that has a `toScreenPoint` method that takes generic input....

Comment: @CKing Yes, but that interface would still be in the same kind of situation: declaring a method returning an implementer. Would that really be acceptable whereas a base class declaring a method returning an inheritor wouldn't? Besides, geometric points are just an example; you could have a large amount of common functionality in the base class. Also, could you elaborate on the generic suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of design is usually a code smell. Base classes should not know about their derived classes because it creates a circular dependency. And circular dependencies usually lead to complicated designs where it's difficult to reason about what classes should be doing. In Java, base classes knowing about their derived classes can even result in deadlock in some rare cases (I don't know about C#).

However, you can break general rules in special cases, when you know exactly what you are doing, specially if what you are trying to achieve is simple enough.

And your case here seems to be simple enough. Having `AbstractPoint` and `ScreenPoint` as different classes is correct. But in fact they "work together": All `AbstractPoint`s should be able to convert to `ScreenPoint` (that's maybe the most important functionality in `AbstractPoint`'s contract?). Since one cannot exist without the other, there is nothing wrong about `AbstractPoint` knowing about `ScreenPoint`.

**Update**

In a different design: Create an interface called `CanonicalPoint`.
`AbstractPoint` has a method called `ToCanonicalPoint`, which returns `CanonicalPoint`.
All derived classes of `AbstractPoint` have to implement this and return `CanonicalPoint`.
`ScreenPoint` is a derived class of `AbstractPoint` which implements the `CanonicalPoint` interface.
You could even have more than one derived class that implements `CanonicalPoint`.
Note: If `AbstractPoint` and `CanonicalPoint` have methods in common, both can implement another
interface called, say, `Pointable`, that declares all of these methods.

Comment: That's a good observation about the conversion being the key thing in the contract. However, I'm getting the feeling that you and some of the commenters think my question is about the specific example in the code, when it's actually about the scenario the code exemplifies. While the example is simple in order to illustrate, in general the domain could be arbitrarily complex, and I'm wondering if there's a way not to break OO best practices while still satisfying the constraint that a bunch of things of the same kind have to be convertible to a canonical thing of that kind.

Comment: Ok, I will post an alternate solution. See above.

Comment: Note, above you can also play with the names. Create an interface called `ScreenPoint`. `AbstractPoint` has a method called `ToScreenPoint`, which returns `ScreenPoint`. All derived classes of `AbstractPoint` have to implement this and return `CanonicalPoint`. `ScreenPointImpl` is a derived class of `AbstractPoint` which implements the `ScreenPoint` interface. You could even have more than one derived class that implements `ScreenPoint`.

Comment: Your suggestion for the base class method to return an instance of an interface that the derived class implements would certainly work, with the interface now representing the canonical representation instead of the derived class. However, this would seem to violate DRY, since you'd have to declare the same elements in both the base class and the interface. That doesn't quite feel right.

Comment: @MiroslavPolicki Hmm, that's easy to solve. The base class and the interface could both implement another interface (say, Pointable interface) that has the methods that CanonicalPoint and AbstractPoint have in common, if any.

Comment: After reviewing all the answers and comments, I find that your interface solution is the only one that satisfies the requirements of the problem. However, even then, the solution ends up being two interfaces; one of them a marker interface which doesn't really add any benefit except for the avoidance of an explicit reference to a derived class by a base class, at the expense of a more complex design. In light of all this, I'm inclined to conclude that this is one of those cases where it's justified to go against conventional wisdom, as you originally suggested.

Answer (score 2):

I feel that the [Single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) in [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) has been overlooked. The `AbstractPoint` and its concrete implementation `ScreenPoint`, are essentially storing **data**, e.g. `X, Y`, unique to the class group. As well the base class `AbstractPoint` is trying to enforce what seems like the [Factory Method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) inline (minus an interface being returned). While I think it to be appropriate and necessary to have logical operations on the **data** in the `AbstractPoint` and/or `ScreenPoint` classes; I feel like a separate `ScreenPointFactory` class implementing *Factory Method pattern* to instantiate the `ScreenPoint` is much needed here.

If you are needing to create thousands of `ScreenPoint` classes, having the extra virtual method calls such as `ToScreenPoint()` and extra object size could have negative performance issues. Considering to use the [Flyweight pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) in this scenario could help load times. For *Flyweight pattern* to be successful, you will need the *Factory Method pattern* to be implemented as the *Flyweight pattern* is used within the *factory*. Since there will be factories, you will need an `IPoint` interface and simply derive `AbstractPoint` off of the interface `IPoint`. `IPoint` will simply hold `X, Y` for now. The remaining point types gain the `IPoint` interface through inheritance of `AbstractPoint`. Since there will be group of related point types, e.g. `ArbitraryPoint`, `ScreenPoint`, they can all be instantiated via an [Abstract Factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern).

[Programming to interfaces, not implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697783/what-does-program-to-interfaces-not-implementations-mean) principle will be important here. To pull off the functionality of `ToScreenPoint()` in what I am describing, I would remove `ToScreenPoint()` from the **Point** classes completely and instead, I would create an `ArbitraryTransformation` object configured upon startup. I would use [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) to place the `ArbitraryTransformation` object into the appropriate factory during [IOC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) configuration. Then when the *Abstract Factory* methods are called to create any new variations of your screen points… they are created **with the arbitrary transformation already calculated**, as each independent factory method within the `AbstractFactory` will use the appropriately configured `ArbitraryTransformation` to perform the calculation.

Doing all this will put less stress on your design, and will keep your objects a bit lighter and loosely coupled. I feel you are dealing with complexities here to where you can figure out what I just said above simply with the [GoF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns) pattern language. <strike>However, if you or anyone would rather have the coded samples, I can come back in and provide a sample solution. Just seems like a whole lot of code to link, if you do not exactly need or want what I am suggesting.</strike>

I went ahead and developed a sample solution on my GitHub called [Point Example](https://github.com/OhRyanOh/PointExample). Let me know what you think.

Also, for every design pattern added here, it will introduce extra layers of complexity to your app, so while that can be a problem in itself, I think it will lend itself to be useful for what you need.

---

### Update

In the point example I decided to do a very simple implementation of [Object Pool pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern) instead of the mentioned `Flyweight pattern` above. I showed placement of a performance improvement pattern in doing so in case a solid example was needed. Although there are better ways to give the implementation, the `Object Pool pattern` as used in the `ScreenPointFactory` is a mere functional place holder.

I have updated the code in the [Point Example](https://github.com/OhRyanOh/PointExample) to reflect naming things `Flyweight pattern` to `Object Pool pattern`. Sorry for any confusion. Also, here are answers to Miroslav Policki's questions in the comments section below:

---

### Question 1:

*1. It seems your motivation for moving onto the Factory Method pattern is the ability to use the Flyweight pattern. However, as I understand it, the Flyweight pattern is a performance optimization, and as such shouldn't be applied prematurely. So, in situations where the Flyweight pattern is unnecessary, would you still proceed with the rest of your design, and why? – Miroslav Policki*

**Answer:** I made a correction referencing the `Object Pool pattern` instead of `Flyweight pattern` to the code. Regardless of my naming mishap, both `Object Pool pattern` and `Flyweight pattern` are performance optimizations. However, my motivation for creating factories is out of habbit, as it is common to do so to encapsulate creational logic. Yes my implementation in the example code of `Object Pool pattern` was never asked for, and it is a perfomance optimization that is applied prematurely in this situation. However, I felt it to be more of an educational bonus, if somebody was wondering where to place performance enhancements in this paradigm, without spending too much time. I gave `ArbitraryPointFactory` no performance enhancements to show the flexibility of the factories.

Also, **yes**, I would absolutely use the *Factories* to create any variations of points, as from the given example there were mulitple concrete types. Keeping the factories around will keep instantiations of point ojbects in a single location in code, and factories will yield a single place in code to modify creation logic. Factories are useful for simple and complex objects, and allow us to program to interfaces, and not concrete implementations. However, like most design patterns, I would not suggest for anyone to have to indroduce factories into their code, if there is only one concrete point object or one place in thier code that needs to call the `new` operator for an object. However if you have two instances in your code where the `new` operator is being used to create concrete points, etc then it may be nice to have a factory so you can make a change in one place in a factory, instead of having to search through code and run into the possibilty of not updating all places appropriately if there are changes to the way the object needs to be created.

### Question 2:

*2. You apply the transformation on a point during its creation in the corresponding factory method. However, this is different from the semantics in my example, because each `ArbitraryPoint` has internal state which can change at any time, and thus yield different `ScreenPoint`s. How would you incorporate this into your design? – Miroslav Policki*

**Answer:** Part of me wants to say the name `ScreenPoint` has made me performance antsy, and I am striving for a relevant implementation. The other part of me wants to say I would have designed it this way regardless. However, I know you are suggesting `ScreenPoint` being pixel related, etc...  is **not** the case, it is just another arbitrary example. I will give you my valid example first though. I was contemplating the creation of thousands apon thousands of `ScreenPoint` renders in a video game, possibly where we may also be storing the color of each pixel per screen point, and we are just creating a full screen render of throw away `ScreenPoint` objects. So lets say there is a double buffer of screen points going, where we are drawing two screen renders at a time. We would just be calculating the render of game object coordinates to real world coordinates and then mapping them to a 2D screen render 30 to 60+ times a second. In this scenario, I wouldn't care about modifying existing renders `X,Y` data, rather than just creating a new set of `ScreenPoint` objects for each additional render. Now that can seem wasteful, and `Flyweight pattern` could help to overcome having to create so many new objects at runtime as there would be only one `ScreenPoint` object, and the implemenation of each `X,Y` would be encapsulated to an internal `Array` or `Dictionary`. However, again I was also considering [object size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694423/size-of-a-class-object-in-net) and how many method and virtual method pointers each object had to maintain along with the data, when creating or dealing with thousands of `ScreenPoint` objects very quickly when thinking of my design. The design allows `ScreenPoint` to be purely a data object, nothing more.

Back to your semantics though, I achieved the calculation through object composition via the `ArbitraryTransformation` object and related interfaces. There is nothing preventing us the ability to compose the `AbitraryTransformation` object with your `ArbitraryPoint` object or a `NoOpTransformation` with your `ScreenPoint` to be utilized in object properties or mutator methods to perform the calculation from within the `ArbitraryPoint` or `ScreenPoint` objects respectively. This is where `Has-A` is better than `Is-A` comes into play with object composition. The factory is a good place to compose your objects together with other objects, e.g. `Has-A`. We may later want to use a `MochTransformation` object in unit tests with a `MochScreenPointFactory` to be able to actually test a `ScreenPoint` object's functionality or math. So sticking with this paradigm allows for this to naturally happen in configuration (IOC Container buildup), keeping what may be a complex algorithm or impossible scenario to test against in it's own replaceable tranformation object. So again, **Nothing** is preventing you from keeping the `ToScreenPoint()` method on your `ScreenPoint` object if you like having the interface there instead of handing off responsibility to the factory. My re-organization of where the calculation was happening was geared towards keeping the `ScreenPoint` simple and small. It's single responsibility was in just keeping up with data.

I also am seeing that in your example you are using the `new` operator for `ScreenPoint` in two places, or each `ToScreenPoint` method. With the appropriate injected factory into each point, the factory method could be called from the `ToScreenPoint()` method of each type of point. There is nothing preventing this either, and there is some other point the code will be instantiating the first `ScreenPoint` or `AbstractPoint` which could be delegated to a factory instead of setup in each location a `ScreenPoint` needs to be created. Also, I do not like how the `AbstractPoint` class is returning a single concrete instance of `ScreenPoint` rather than an interface. You have simply embedded the notion of an `Abstract Factory pattern` for a family of objects, yet every family returns a concrete instance of one type, rather than an interface. Because of this your calling code will need to be context aware regardless. This is why I broke out in my example the notion that `ScreenPoint` and `ArbitraryPoint` derived from the same interface and yet `ArbitraryPoint` had it's own extra / custom data. If I need to perform the conversion from arbitrary point to screen point, I had to be context aware anyways enough to use the correct Factory method to create a new point with the correct calculation, which in turn utilizes the `ArbitraryTransformation` calculation for instance at the moment of object creation.

I think where my example may differ from yours in intent, is that you wish for me in the `IOCConfig.cs` to create `ScreenPointFactory` as follows `new ScreenPointFactory(new ScreenTransformation())` to where instead of being a *No-Op* type operation it does the work of conversion, and that `ArbitraryPointFactory` had the No-Op. I would then be able to pass in the `X,Y` or perhaps the `IPoint` interface to the `ScreenPointFactory` or the correct `PointFactory` method to then do some conversion from `ArbitraryPoint` perhaps to what could be a `ScreenPoint`. So in this instance, I would be modifying the data of an `ArbitraryPoint` that may be a point on a video game model, and then use my `ScreenPointFactory` to create a `ScreenPoint` from an `ArbitraryPoint` which does all the coordinate conversions. Then instead of modifying the `ScreenPoint` calcs directly, I would still be modifying the video game model directly or the original `ArbitraryPoint`, to then throw away my generated `ScreenPoint` and generate a new `ScreenPoint` by calling the `ScreenPointFactory` to update my `ScreenPoint` location from the values of the original `ArbitraryPoint`. Dealing with these complexities will definitely warrent the use of the techniques I am presenting here with Factories. Also simplifying your object models to be used in a manner that makes sense to the application that is using it.

Anyways tag me back if any of what I have said is questionable or if you would like me to change the sample code around in any way to match my last paragraph. The *only* other way I might stick to something similar to what you have in your example is to try and implement the [Adapter pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern). Then I have the ability to go from one interface to another for instance, so from `ScreenPoint` to `ArbitraryPoint` and vice versa without forcing them to derive from the same interface or base class. Yet providing some calculation and conversion back and forth. My implementing code would always look to the Adapter class to pull back the data I wish to operate on and then convert back and forth. Either way I guess the main design principles I have tried to express are (Found in the book *Head First Design Patterns*):

- Program to an interface, not an implemenation.
- Favor composition over inheritance. (`Has-A` is better than `Is-A`)
- Dependency Inversion Principle (Depend upon abstractions. Do not depend upon concrete classes.)

  - No variable should hold a reference to a concrete class. (If you use new, you'll be holding a reference to a concrete class. Use a factory to get around that!)
  - No class should derive from a concrete class. (If you derive from a concrete class, you're depending on a concrete class. Derive from an abstraction, like an interface or an abstract class.)
  - No method should override an implemented method of any of its base classes. (If you override an implemented method, then your base class wasn't really an abstraction to start with.)

    Funny thing is the book goes forward to mention for `Dependency Inversion Principle`, that if you follow all three of those design guidelines with no exceptions that you would never be able to write a single program. So I will say to you that try to aim towards these principles, but only where they make the best sense. For any of the design patterns or principles there are both pros and cons. However, at least with the design patterns they are more like templates to do what you want from already solved problems. So plug them in and adapt them where they make sense to your design. Others will be familiar with your design and can jump right in with your naming strategy and add to your code.

Comment: The answer including the code is quite detailed; thank you for the effort. I do have some questions.

1. It seems your motivation for moving onto the Factory Method pattern is the ability to use the Flyweight pattern. However, as I understand it, the Flyweight pattern is a performance optimization, and as such shouldn't be applied prematurely. So, in situations where the Flyweight pattern is unnecessary, would you still proceed with the rest of your design, and why?

Comment: 2. You apply the transformation on a point during its creation in the corresponding factory method. However, this is different from the semantics in my example, because each `ArbitraryPoint` has internal state which can change at any time, and thus yield different `ScreenPoint`s. How would you incorporate this into your design?

Comment: Miroslav, my complete apologies. I have used *Object Pool pattern*, and not *Flyweight pattern* in the *Point Example* code. I will update the code and answer above with an appropriate response to your two questions. May take me a bit. However, yes I got carried away making design choices thinking of many objects due to the example being a screen point, and no it was not a full implementation of *Object Pool pattern*, more of a placeholder.

Comment: It would be great if you could update your code on GitHub as well, just to make sure I (or any other reader) have a correct understanding of your latest update to the answer.

Comment: The source code is up to date with the *Object Pool pattern* rename. Was this okay as is, or were you wanting me to do add the **ScreenTransformation** class and changes I mentioned in the Update section? I was not positive if this was what you were looking for?

Comment: Yes, I meant the ScreenTransformation class and changes you mentioned in the Update section, if it's not too much trouble.

Comment: Gotcha, I will try to address this at some point this week. Will notify you again when it is complete by editing this comment.

Answer (score 1):

You have complicated things without reason. If a class cannot implement the specification of the base class you are violating Liskovs Substitution principle.

An alternative is an interface that declares that an arbitrary object can be represented as coordinates:

```
public interface IScreenPointProvider
{
    ScreenPoint ToPoint();
}
```

Then it doesn't matter what the object is or what its internal handling of coordinates is.

Also do not forget that inheritance is about `is-a` relationship. If any of the sub classes do not support what the base class provide, it's not really a `is-a` relationship. That typically indicates that the base class really is a utility class or that the defined hierarchy isn't well designed.

Comment: But in this case the classes can indeed implement the specification of the base class. They can all implement `ToScreenPoint()`. Even `ScreenPoint` can implement `ToScreenPoint()` by simply returning itself. This is like `Object.ToString` returning `String`, which is derived from `Object`.

Comment: He stated *"an abstract point has no coordinate system information, so the values of X and Y are meaningless"*. No inheritance hierarchy should be built on a false grounds. My alternative do not use inheritance for that reason.

Comment: Yes, but I believe he wanted to write that "an abstract point may have some arbitrary coordinate system information, which is defined by each derived class". Clearly ScreenPoint has meaning (X,Y in the screen). He wrote (in a comment) that: "While the example is simple in order to illustrate, ... [what I really want to know is] if there's a way not to break OO best practices while still satisfying the constraint that a bunch of things of the same kind have to be convertible to a canonical thing of that kind."

Comment: Abstract base classes should be used when there is a least common denominator. An empty base class do not have that, nor do a base class with properties that doesn't mean anything to the base class itself.  Thus it's poor OOP design to introduce a base class then, an interface is a much better fit since it specifically add a certain functionality without dictating what the class do otherwise.

Comment: My point is that if the base class introduce common behavior (methods that change the object state) of point types, then yes, a base class is a good fit. However, if the base class is empty or just contain properties it's not really a valid base class in OOP sense.

Comment: But that's not his question. His example is simple in order to illustrate. It doesn't mean that he's asking about a base class that's empty.

Comment: As MarcG has said, my question is not about the concrete code. In general, the base class would hold properties that are common to and methods that can be used on all objects of the type. I like the IScreenPointProvider solution, however it is limited: if I have a bunch of IScreenPointProvider references, I can get ScreenPoints out of them. But if I want to have a bunch of points, apply a common operation on them (for example rotate them around the origin, wherever that may be), and convert them to ScreenPoints, then I need to have AbstractPoint references, not IScreenPointProvider references.