# What exactly can we describe Factory Method of design pattern?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, software-design, software-quality

I am confused with the concept ? Is it just as simple as incorporating a static method to return the object instead of a constructor ? So that client doesn't need to change the code while we update the library or there is something more to it ?

Comment: Can you please write some code example and elaborate bit more?

Comment: The answer is that if you do `new X()` you definitely get an instance of the concrete class `X`. A factory method `X.newInstance()` has the freedom in its implementation to create a subclass of `X`. e.g. `public X newInstance() { if( return  (Environment.isDebug()) ? new DebuggingX() : new X())` -- but you could have found this anywhere the pattern is discussed e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern or any book on OO patterns.

Answer (score 0):

The book [Head First Design Patterns](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596007126.do) will be your definitive guide for Java. That is a great book. If you check out my answer to this [Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46985824/is-it-acceptable-to-return-a-canonical-representation-subclass-from-an-abstract/47009186#47009186), you will be able to see my implementation for an [ArbitraryPointFactory](https://github.com/OhRyanOh/PointExample/blob/master/PointExample.Common/Factories/ArbitraryPointFactory.cs) class in the [Point Example](https://github.com/OhRyanOh/PointExample) code that uses the [Factory Method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) as well as how it differs from [Abstract Factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) seen in the [Point Factory](https://github.com/OhRyanOh/PointExample/blob/master/PointExample.Common/Factories/PointFactory.cs) class. Although this answer is presented with C# code samples, the design pattern language I am using to describe their usage, should warrant you an answer.

What you are thinking of in your question is not a design pattern at all. This static method that returns an object to encapsulate the instantiation, is known as the [Simple Factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming)) as seen in the Wiki page. The `Factory Method` pattern more or less abstracts the type being returned via an interface. This is typically done where the sole job of the `factory method` class is to control creation of the objects for one `concrete` class that implements the interface being returned. The `Abstract Factory` provides encapsulation for a group of related products. In my example I was showing for different types of points, however they could implement different interfaces and all use the same `Abstract Factory`.

The idea is that you are programming to interfaces, not implementations. True factories pull creation logic to a single location in your application and encapsulate the instantiation via interfaces.